# add key and value to the last duplicated object in array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of object and I want to add a key and value to the objects that are duplicated.

```
[
  {type: "text", content: ""},
  {type: "option", content: ""},
  {type: "text", content: ""},
  {type: "link", url: ""},
  {type: "text", content: ""},
  {type: "text", content: ""},
  {type: "text", content: ""},
]
```

how should I add my key and value to the last text type, its dynamic and will change.

result:

```
[
  {type: "text", content: "", hasImage: true},
  {type: "option", content: ""},
  {type: "text", content: "", hasImage: true },
  {type: "link", url: ""},
  {type: "text", content: ""},
  {type: "text", content: ""},
  {type: "text", content: "", hasImage: true },
]
```

Comment: Last... or third? Could you please be more specific about what is the expected result?

Comment: Duplication for what? type or content?

Comment: So you want to find all array entries of type `"text"` that are either the last entry of the array or are followed by an object with a type not equal to `"text"`? And to these entries/objects, you want to add a new property?

Comment: want to have the result. how add hasImage: true to those objects

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
const arr = [
  {type: "IMAGE", url: ""},     // << given an IMAGE here
  {type: "text", content: ""},  // ...skip this one
  {type: "text", content: ""},  // ...skip this one
  {type: "text", content: ""},  // << add: hasImage:true
  {type: "LINK", url: ""},      // ...nothing to do here
  {type: "IMAGE", url: ""},     // << IMAGE again!
  {type: "text", content: ""},  // ...skip this one
  {type: "text", content: ""},  // ...skip this one
  {type: "text", content: ""},  // << add hasImage:true 
];

let hasImage = false;
arr.forEach((item, i, list) => {
  const prevItem = list[i-1];
  const nextItem = list[i+1];
  // If item is type "IMAGE", set hasImage flag to true,
  if (!hasImage && item.type === "IMAGE") hasImage = true;

  // If the hasImage flag is true,
  // and if we reached an item that is not of type "text" 
  // check the previous item "text" type, and add the hasImage property to it 
  if (hasImage && prevItem && (item.type !== "text" || !nextItem) && prevItem.type === "text") {
    list[!nextItem ? i : i-1].hasImage = true;
    // Finally, reset the flag for next iterations
    hasImage = false; 
  }
});

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: I need a better solution without forEach, do you have any idea?

Comment: @FatemehQasemkhani Better idea? Define why using [Array.prototype.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) would not be actually *the best idea*? What stops you to use the technologies and methods JavaScript has to offer you.